# How to do response/request URB interrupt in libusb?

Tags: c, linux, usb, reverse-engineering, libusb

I'm trying to replicate a Windows program on Linux. The program talks to the USB device.
Now I'm stuck on the part where the device sends URB_interrupt IN first, and the host answers. The capture looks like this (and this is the result I want to have):

```
Frame 29: 72 bytes on wire (576 bits), 72 bytes captured (576 bits) on interface usbmon0, id 0
USB URB
    [Source: 1.16.2]
    [Destination: host]
    URB id: 0xffff8d92d4ece840
    URB type: URB_COMPLETE ('C')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x82, Direction: IN
    Device: 16
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: present (0)
    URB sec: 1664781571
    URB usec: 862138
    URB status: Success (0)
    URB length [bytes]: 8
    Data length [bytes]: 8
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 8
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000200, Dir IN
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
Leftover Capture Data: 0508ff0000000000

Frame 30: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits) on interface usbmon0, id 0
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.16.2]
    URB id: 0xffff8d9321011cc0
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x82, Direction: IN
    Device: 16
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('<')
    URB sec: 1664781571
    URB usec: 865989
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 8
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 8
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000200, Dir IN
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
```

It looks like the device sends the answer first (URB type is 'URB_COMPLETE'), and after that, the host answers ('URB_SUBMIT'). Previously I have only encountered the opposite situation (i. e. swap order of the captured packets) and I know how to do it, but I have no idea how to do the upper-mentioned one.

I do the URB interrupt by the following function:

```
#define INTR_EP_IN 0x82
#define INTR_LENGTH 8
typedef unsigned char byte_t;

/* Proper opening, kernel detaching, and interface claiming... */

static int send_interrupt(libusb_device_handle *handle)
{
    byte_t *packet;
    int transferred = 0;
    short sent;

    packet = calloc(INTR_LENGTH, 1);
    sent = libusb_interrupt_transfer(handle, INTR_EP_IN, packet, INTR_LENGTH,
                                     &transferred, 10);
    free(packet);
    /* Note: always TIMEOUT_ERROR, but the packet gets captured anyway */
    /*
    if(sent != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, INTRRPT_ERR_MSG, libusb_strerror(sent));
    */
    return sent;
}
```

I've tried to change libusb_interrupt_transfer parameters, but nothing gave me the desired result.
Every time I get something like the following:

```
Frame 30: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits) on interface usbmon0, id 0
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.6.2]
    URB id: 0xffff922c3bd69540
    URB type: URB_SUBMIT ('S')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x82, Direction: IN
    Device: 6
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: not present ('<')
    URB sec: 1668092600
    URB usec: 503008
    URB status: Operation now in progress (-EINPROGRESS) (-115)
    URB length [bytes]: 8
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Response in: 31]
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 8
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000200, Dir IN
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0

Frame 31: 64 bytes on wire (512 bits), 64 bytes captured (512 bits) on interface usbmon0, id 0
USB URB
    [Source: 1.6.2]
    [Destination: host]
    URB id: 0xffff922c3bd69540
    URB type: URB_COMPLETE ('C')
    URB transfer type: URB_INTERRUPT (0x01)
    Endpoint: 0x82, Direction: IN
    Device: 6
    URB bus id: 1
    Device setup request: not relevant ('-')
    Data: present (0)
    URB sec: 1668092600
    URB usec: 506108
    URB status: No such file or directory (-ENOENT) (-2)
    URB length [bytes]: 0
    Data length [bytes]: 0
    [Request in: 30]
    [Time from request: 0.003100000 seconds]
    [bInterfaceClass: Unknown (0xffff)]
    Unused Setup Header
    Interval: 8
    Start frame: 0
    Copy of Transfer Flags: 0x00000200, Dir IN
    Number of ISO descriptors: 0
```

Which totally isn't what I intend to have.

I'm assuming I don't know something as I am not an expert in the USB protocol. There's also a chance that libusb just doesn't allow to do such transfer. In this case, I should do this via corresponding syscalls, but this is the last resort for me.

Comment: In the first trace, why do you think the two frames are related?

Comment: @stark, in the full trace, these frames are the first and the last occurrences of urb_interrupt, everything else is regular request/response urb_control. So I suppose they cannot be related to anything else

Comment: You might have misunderstood how the capturing work. I guess you are using Wireshark with libpcap. It records 2 events for each USB packet: a submit and a completion event. The first trace indicates that the software likely queues multiple USB transfers (URBs) such that a new URB is immediately submitted when an packet has been received.

Comment: also, note that the URB id is not the same in the first dump. But it has to be the same if they are related